The number of small sum-free subsets of $[n]$
I'm interested in the following question:

Can we bound the number of sum-free subsets of size $k$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, as a function of $n$ and $k$? In particular, what can we say about a function $f(n)$ such that for all $k\lesssim f(n)$, almost all size $k$ subsets of $[n]$ are sum-free?

Surprisingly, I can't find any literature on this problem; it seems that the focus is more on large sum-free sets rather than small ones. I would appreciate a reference if one exists.

This does not directly answer your question, but in case you are not aware of it the so-called Cameron-Erdos conjecture, solved by Ben Green, shows that the number of sum-free subsets of $[n]$ is about $2^{n/2}$.

From the accepted answer I can infer that sum-free means  "No element can be written as a sum of two elements" and not "No element can be written as a sum of a finite subset of elements". Maybe it should be included in the question.

Note: I'm working mod $n$ here, which is directly transferable to the integers for the lower bound, and for the upper bound it's only a multiplicative error of a constant which doesn't affect the conclusion.
Any $f(n) = o(n^{\frac13})$ works. Note that for $k = o(\sqrt n)$ almost all sequences chosen with replacement from $[n]$ have no repetitions, so it suffices to prove that for almost all sequences of length $o(n^{\frac13})$ are sum free. Now each triples of indices $1 \leq i, j, l \leq k$ give a condition $a_i + a_j \neq a_l$, which clearly fails with probability $\frac1n$. Now a simple union bound gives that the probability that $a$ isn't sum free is at most $\frac{k^3}n$, which for $k = o(n^\frac13{})$ tends to $0$.
On the other hand, this condition is also necessary. Again, we can move to sequences, and now we'll use Bonferroni inequalities with $K = 2$. Any pair of different conditions are linearly independent, so both fail with a probability $\frac1{n^2}$, so the probability of a failure is at least $\frac{k^3}n - \frac{\binom{k^3}2}{n^2}$, and as it tends to $0$ so must $\frac{k^3}n$.
